# why cant use dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to populate a dropdownlist from json, I can't select the ddl from the html page :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPopUp" runat="server" /> //HTML

//JaveScript 1 - returns empty ddl
ar DdlPopUp = "<%=ddlPopUp.ClientID %>";
function fillDDL(data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data.Data);      
        var myList = "";       
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
             myList += "<option>"+ obj[i] +"</option>";        
        }     
         DdlPopUp.html(myList);      
    }
//JaveScript 2 - dll always null
  function fillDDL(data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data.Data);
        var dll = document.getElementById('ddlPopUp');            
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {         
            dll.appendChild(obj[i]);
        }              
    }
```

Why it doesn't work ? what to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the DDL on the client side using jQuery, you need to do this:

```
var DdlPopUp = $('#<%=ddlPopUp.ClientID %>');
```